# Obey to the order being dropped and display placeholder while dropping with jQueryUI draggable/droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two unordered lists. The functionality required is;
1) The left pane (#sortable) cannot be sorted within itself
2) The right panel (#sortable1) can be sorted within itself
3) Items from the left panel can be dragged and dropped onto the panel on the right
4) Items from the right panel cannot bet dragged and dropped onto the panel on the left.
5) Items being dragged should have a placeholder available to drop anywhere in between the items on the right panel.

At the moment, the following code does 1,2,3,4. When it comes to 5, currently the dropped item is placed on the top of the list on the right (with .prepend).

What I can't figure out is, how to have the item to be dropped anywhere in the list (not just to the beginning or the end) and have a placeholder while the item being dragged in the panel on the right?

JQUERY

```
$('#sortable li').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    connectWith: '#sortable1',
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: 0.5,
    zIndex: 10
});

$('#sortable1').sortable({
    connectWith: '#sortable',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    containment: '#sortable1'
  }).droppable({
      accept: '#sortable li',
      activeClass: 'highlight',
      drop: function (event, ui) {
          var $li = $('<li>').addClass('ui-state-highlight').html(ui.draggable.html());
      $li.prependTo(this);
      }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4778">Item 1 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4777">Item 2 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4773">Item 3 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="4772">Item 4 Right</li>

</ul>

<ul id="sortable1">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="4778">Item 1 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="4777">Item 2 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="4773">Item 3 Right</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="4772">Item 4 Right</li>

</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the connectWith option of the jquery draggable, make use of the [connectToSortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable) option. This will have two advantages over your current code.

1. You will get the necessary functionality you are looking for without affecting other functionalities.
2. You wont have to define your #sortable1 as a droppable